# Wordle Clone & Local Storage: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, getelementbyid

In creating a [themed Wordle clone for my site](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/borodle-word-game/), I want to use Local Storage to preserve a user's game state. For the most part, I think I have achieved this – but am currently encountering an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')` error that I can't get to the bottom of.

The impact of this error is that, on refresh during an 'active' game, the keyboard refuses to render – and the game's tiles expand to the width the keyword would've been. The error message suggests that it can't match with an ID within the HTML, but I've checked this and the `getElementByID` matches up with the div class of `game-keyboard`.

The (relevant part of the) JS code is...
(full JS code can be found [here](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/js/borodle.js))

```
const storedKeyboardContainer =
        window.localStorage.getItem("keyboardContainer");
      if (storedKeyboardContainer) {
        document.getElementById("game-keyboard").innerHTML =
          storedKeyboardContainer;
  
        addKeyboardClicks();
      }
```

and

```
function preserveGameState() {
      window.localStorage.setItem("guessedWords", JSON.stringify(guessedWords));
  
      const keyboardContainer = document.getElementById("game-keyboard");
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        "keyboardContainer",
        keyboardContainer.innerHTML
      );
  
      const boardContainer = document.getElementById("game-container");
      window.localStorage.setItem("boardContainer", boardContainer.innerHTML);
    }
```

The error message I am receiving ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at loadLocalStorage (borodle.js:3:158)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (borodle.js:1:1547)
```

The HTML element that houses the keyboard...

```
<div id="game-keyboard">
                    <div class="keyboard-row">
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="q">q</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="w">w</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="e">e</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="r">r</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="t">t</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="y">y</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="u">u</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="i">i</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="o">o</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="p">p</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="keyboard-row">
                        <div class="borodle-half"></div>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="a">a</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="s">s</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="d">d</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="f">f</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="g">g</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="h">h</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="j">j</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="k">k</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="l">l</button>
                        <div class="borodle-half"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="keyboard-row">
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="enter" class="wide-button">Enter</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="z">z</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="x">x</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="c">c</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="v">v</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="b">b</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="n">n</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="m">m</button>
                        <button class="keyboard-button" data-key="del" class="wide-button">DEL</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I used a tutorial to build the initial game and then [a second part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF4O1wvyVow) to incorporate local storage for the preservation of the game state. Is there a fundamental error in the JS code (which I ended up amalgamating) – or is it perhaps related to the order in which elements are executed as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem now appears to be solved. After reviewing the JS file several times, I found a mis-labelled attribute. After changing this, the issue (and error message) is no longer present.